# Why is my right hand expression in a reactive variable reactive?

Tags: variables, svelte

So I have this simple Svelte code:

```js
let formValues: AppointmentWrite;
$: formValues = {
    ...appointment
}

$: console.log(appointment);
```

`formValues` has a property `comments` which is bound to an input. When I type something into the input, the reactive `console.log` in the snippet is being triggered.

If I omit the `appointments` spread operator and change the code to

```js
$: formValues = {
   comments: '',
}

$: console.log(appointment);
```

then the `console.log` is not being triggered anymore. Why is that? Why would the `console.log` get triggered in the first snippet at all, if the `appointment` variable is on the right side of a reactive expression, and doesn't change?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction that can be executed in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/)?

Comment: @brunnerh I managed to workaround this, but here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/60487dd8d6f941b3bc2e0d72124a2abb?version=3.44.3) if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

According to an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7045), this is expected behavior as of Svelte 3.2.1

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

```js
let formValues: AppointmentWrite;
$: updateFormValues(appointment);

const updateFormValues = (...args: any[]) => {
    formValues = {...appointment};
}

$: console.log(appointment);
```

now `appointment` won't be updated when `formValues` changes and the `console.log` won't be called.